# Why cmake can't find libvtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets.so?

Tags: python, cmake, vtk, lammps

I have this warning while compiling with cmake:

```
The imported target "vtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets" references the file
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets.so"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.
```

I tried a lot of solutions like installing libproj or libvtk6dev

I am on Debian 10 and it's happened when i want to install granoo, lammps and others that refer to VTK.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Are you following a tutorial of some kind? It may be helpful to provide a link to such tutorial.

Comment: yes it's came from https://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/Build_cmake.html

Comment: We could hardly give more "Possible reasons" than CMake shows to you. If you expect none of these reasons is applicable for your case, then give mode details about your VTK installation.

Comment: i have found a solution but seems quite dangerous. I made a a symbolic link `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vtk/libvtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets.x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets.so`

Comment: for my installation i try with `sudo apt-get install libvtk7.1` and others versions like 6.3 and 6-dev. Also add python-vtk